# Why do I see multiple interpreters in my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

When I open the Jupyter Notebook web app, I see multiple interpreters:

Ideally, I should just see the Python 3* I have installed via HomeBrew:

> /usr/local/bin/python3 --> 3.9.9

and the 2.* one that comes preinstalled on macOS

> /usr/bin/python --> 2.7.18

non of which are detected by the Jupyter Notebook!

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

#### To delete Interperters:

Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to get the paths of all your kernels.
Then simply uninstall your unwanted-kernel

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall unwanted-kernel
```

you can also just run

```
# List all kernels and grap the name of the kernel you want to remove
jupyter kernelspec list
# Remove it
jupyter kernelspec remove <kernel_name>
```

The docs has a list of the common paths for kernels to be stored in: [common paths](http://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs)

---

#### to add your interpreters:

terminate jupyter, activate the environment you want to add a kernel for, and then run this command (requires `conda install ipykernel`):

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <kernel_name> --display-name "<Name_to_display>"
```

Make sure to replace `<kernel_name>` and `<Name_to_display>` to the name of your environment.

Once you installed the kernel, you can change to it through the above menu and even through this code snippet from a Jupyter cell:

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.session.restart({kernel_name: '<kernel_name>'})
```

you can read more [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3)